# jQuery click event triggers for all picture objects

Tags: jquery

For my project, I am trying to show picture comments by clicking view comments under each picture. 
The issue is when I click to view comments for one picture, it triggers and opens all the view comments section for all the pictures. Can anyone help!

jQuery:

```
$('.headingone').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var b = $(this).attr("data-target");
  $(b).toggle("slide");
});
```

HTML:

```
<h5 href="" class="headingone"  data-target=".menu">View Comments</h5>
<div class="menu" data-id="{{item.pk}}" style="display:none">
  {% for i in item.piccomments.all %}
    <p class="paratwo" style="margin:0px;"><strong>{{i.author}}</strong> said "{{i.text}}"</p>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `data-target` is pointing to a class. And I suppose that every menu has the same class.

Try:

```
 $('.headingone').click(function(){
    $(this).next().toggle("slide");
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

What luSchink has posted is correct: if you point to a class, it will open all the comments connected to that class. However, this solution only works if your comments with class ".menu" are always the next element (which is in this case).

If you would have other siblings in front of the comments, $(this).next() wouldn't work. For example:

```
<h5 href="" class="headingone"  data-target=".menu">View Comments</h5>
<div class="another-sibling> </div>
<img class="another-sibling" src="/img/another-sibling-2.png">
<div class="menu" data-id="{{item.pk}}" style="display:none">
  {% for i in item.piccomments.all %}
    <p class="paratwo" style="margin:0px;"><strong>{{i.author}}</strong> said "{{i.text}}"</p>
</div>
```

By assuming that {{item.pk}} is the primary key, we can take consider this as an ID. Another solution that will always work **without changing your jquery function** would be by changing the data-target to the id of the menu with the comments:

**HTML (twig file)**

```
<h5 href="" class="headingone"  data-target="#{{item.pk}}">View Comments</h5>
<div class="menu" data-id="{{item.pk}}" id="{{item.pk}}" style="display:none">
{% for i in item.piccomments.all %}
  <p class="paratwo" style="margin:0px;"><strong>{{i.author}}</strong> 
           said "{{i.text}}"
  </p>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.headingone').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var b = $(this).attr("data-target");
  $(b).toggle("slide");
});
```